# Log camel exchange body as string using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-camel, blueprint

I'm trying to log exchange body as a string using log4j.

```
<convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo1" type="java.lang.String"/>
<to id="_to1" uri="log:com.javarticles?level=INFO"/>
```

but it's not logging as string

```
15:09:05,403 | INFO  | qtp938841692-57  | javarticles                      |
198 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.15.1.redhat-620133 | 
Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.lang.String, Body: 
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.HttpHeadersImpl@52767902]
```

Do we have to make extra logic to log exchange body? And how do we log http headers?

Comment: Seems your body contains a bunch of HTTPHeaders..not sure why you have put them as your body. Those headers exist either as exchange headers or exchange properties. You can access them from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only want to log the message body, then use

```
<log message="${body}"/>
```

The log endpoint logs a bunch of details by default, you can turn these on|off using the options listed: http://camel.apache.org/log